# Can I develop ASMX web services in Visual Studio 2008 Standard Edition?

Tags: visual-studio, service, asmx

I need to know if I can develop ASMX web services using VS 2008 Standard Edition, or if I need Professional Edition?

I can't find this anywhere.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can create them in notepad, so I'm sure you can do it in any edition of VS!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. The Express Edition has more limitations, but Standard will allow you to do those web services.

If you need to compare additional items, here is a nice [comparison chart](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=727BCFB0-B575-47AB-9FD8-4EE067BB3A37&displaylang=en).

EDIT: Actually, you can do ASMX web services in Express Edition as well, if you need a free alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, but do you really want to? See "[Microsoft: ASMX Web Services are a “Legacy Technology”](http://johnwsaundersiii.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!600A2BE4A82EA0A6!860.entry)".

Comment: I realize they suck, this is code someone else has already written.

Comment: I didn't suggest they suck. Only that bugs aren't going to be fixed in ASMX or in XML Serialization. That, and most of the problems they've ever had have been fixed - in WCF.

Comment: Besides, just because the code's already written, doesn't imply it would be difficult to convert to WCF. For simple services, the conversion is quite simple. If they don't use SOAP Headers or SoapExtensions, then the conversion is almost mechanical, and you can keep the existing code. Using headers, it's a little more work (not much). Using SoapExtensions requires planning and real work.